# NASM produces error: label 'xxxx' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I am solving a university task using NASM targeting the 8086 CPU and I have written this code:

```
cpu 8086

segment vectors
resb 1024

segment code
..start mov bx, data
       mov ds, bx
       mov bx, stack
       mov ss, bx
       mov sp, bottom

       mov dx, mesg
       mov ah, 9
       int 21h
       
       xor ax, ax
       mov cs:[0], ax  ; Setting the vector for integer division by zero to div44
       mov cs:[2], cs
       
       jmp end3c

div44: xor dx, dx
       mov cx, cs
       mov [cs:div44], dx
       mov [cs:div44+2], cx
       iret

segment data
byte0 db ?
word0 dw ?
mesg db 'Division by zero', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'

segment stack
resb 16
bottom db ?

end3c hlt
```

But I am getting an error:
`Line #32: error: label 'mesg' changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]`. Line 32 is
`mesg db 'Division by zero', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'`

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Apparently you are trying to use nasm to assemble code not written in nasm syntax. Make sure you know what assembler you are supposed to use.

Comment: @Jester this syntax would be valid if they are outputting using `-f obj` output format. In that case `..start` is a special symbol.

Comment: `cs:[0]` and the `?` are invalid in nasm.

Comment: That's a lot of tangential text and explanation for a question that is about an assembly time error message.

Comment: @PeterCordes : build it with `-f obj` as I suggested in my first comment. `..start` is a special NASM label with that output format. When I saw the `..start` it pretty much told me this was NASM. He doesn't show how he assembles/links (he must use something else to linki). This code did assemble for me without error and I saw a bug report somewhere suggesting at one point there was an errant forward reference bug that was fixed (although I can't be 100% sure it applies to this case). When I assembled this it did so without error.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Thanks. Assembles for me, too, with `nasm -f obj`, with 2.16.01.  I had been using the default `-f bin` which I knew didn't make sense for a program that sets DS and SS.  A recent NASM is required for `?` and `cs:[0]` to assemble; NASM 2.15 or so added some compatibility with MASM syntax

Comment: I've discovered that the OP is likely using version 2.15.x. There is a reason I asked for the version they are using. In 2.15.x assembling with `-f obj` produces the lone error `error: label 'mesg''changed during code generation [-w+error=label-redef-late]` on line 32. Prior to 2.15 support for MASM as it is now wasn't added and you'd get a multitude of errrors. I'd recommend the OP upgrade to 2.16 where the bug in NASM seems to be fixed.